# Using jQuery .eq to update value

Tags: jquery

I have a div in a shopping cart that I'm trying to alter the number of items to match the number of items on the left side of the screen. As you press the up and down buttons next to an item the number increments appropriately. However I'm having difficulty accessing the corresponding div in the cart. Right now the number in the cart is stuck on 0. Line 7 of the code is where my problem is I believe.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/richcoy/MHMVC/

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Number Updater</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body_container">
<div id="product_container">
<div id="product_item_one" class="product_box">
    <div class="item_name">Item One</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x80">    
    <div class="product">0</div>
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
</div>

<div id="product_item_two" class="product_box">
    <div class="item_name">Item Two</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x80">    
    <div class="product">0</div>
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
</div>

<div id="product_item_three" class="product_box">
    <div class="item_name">Item Three</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x80">        
    <div class="product">0</div>
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
</div>

<div id="product_item_four" class="product_box">
    <div class="item_name">Item Four</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x80">    
    <div class="product">0</div>
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
</div>

<div id="product_item_five" class="product_box">
    <div class="item_name">Item Five</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x80">        
    <div class="product">0</div>
    <button class="up">Up</button>
    <button class="down">Down</button>
</div>
</div>

<div id="cart_container">
    <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>
    <div id="cart_item_one" class="cart_product">
            <div class="item_name">Item One</div>
            <div class="cart_product_number">0</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cart_item_two" class="cart_product">
            <div class="item_name">Item Two</div>
            <div class="cart_product_number">0</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cart_item_three" class="cart_product">
            <div class="item_name">Item Three</div>
            <div class="cart_product_number">0</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cart_item_four" class="cart_product">
            <div class="item_name">Item Four</div>
            <div class="cart_product_number">0</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cart_item_five" class="cart_product">
            <div class="item_name">Item Five</div>
            <div class="cart_product_number">0</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end #body_container -->
</body>
</html>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num;
    $('.up').click(function() {
        num = parseInt($(this).siblings('.product').text());
        $(this).prevAll('.product').text(num + 1);        
        $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).show();
        $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.cart_product_number').text(num));
    });

    $('.down').click(function() {
        num = parseInt($(this).siblings('.product').text());
        if (num > 0) {
            $(this).siblings('.product').text(num - 1);
        };

        if (parseInt($(this).siblings('.product').text()) == 0) {
            $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).hide();
        } else {
            $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).show();
        }
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num;
    $('.up').click(function() {
        num = parseInt($(this).siblings('.product').text());
        $(this).prevAll('.product').text(num + 1);    
        var box = $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index());
        box.show();
        box.children(".cart_product_number").text(num + 1);
    });
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Simon. That's perfect. I'm pretty new to this jQuery stuff. Got a few books but have not made much headway yet.

Answer (score 0):

The line you pointed us to isn't quite making sense to me.  You have:

```
$('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.cart_product_number').text(num));
```

Breaking that down, you're doing an `eq()` on this:

```
$(this).closest('.cart_product_number').text(num)
```

which is setting the text of `.cart_product_num` and then returning that object which you then feed to `.eq()` which expects an integer, not a jQuery object.  So this line of code is just wrong all the way around.  If you explain what you were trying to accomplish with that line, we could probably help more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.up, .down').on('click', function() {
        var productElem = $(this).siblings('.product'),
            dir = $(this).is('.down'),
            num = parseInt(productElem.text());
        if (num==1 && dir) {
            productElem.text('0');
            $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).hide();
        }else{
            productElem.text(num + (dir?-1:+1));
            $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).show()
                              .find('.cart_product_number').text(num + (dir?-1:+1));
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MHMVC/4/)